# Безопасно ли хранить данные в config.php?

Tags: php

Добрый день! У меня возник такой вопрос. Вот часто вижу, как программисты php в файл config.php суют данные о сервере базы данных, логин и пароль к базе данных, делают там подключение к БД, обращаются к таблицам, совершают операции над записями. А безопасно ли так поступать? Ведь по сути данные предоставляются на блюдечке злоумышленнику, чтобы он мог воспользоваться данными и попасть в базу данных без всякого шифрования. Поправьте меня, если я утрирую эту проблему безопасности... Или код php, который не выводится на экране, невозможно никак прочитать/взломать?

Comment: А как Вы собираетесь по другому хранить данные для подключения к бд?
Далеко не все данные хранимые в php файлах могут быть выведены на экран.
Что бы их "прочитать" надо либо получить доступ к серверу (ftp/ssh/sftp) и открыть файл со стороны сервера, либо надо знать как вывести любую переменную php скрипта будучи при этом подключенным как клиент по http. 
Не давайте переменным очевидных названий, фильтруйте все данные получаемые от пользователей (вообще все, даже куки, и файлы).
юзайте htaccess.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Сделайте его ответом, я отмечу плюсом ответ. Просто файл config.php кажется таким предсказуемым мне. Что кажется, что можно найти лазейку для взлома данных и получения доступа к БД. Вообще какие современные тенденции взлома сайтов? Как их ломают обычно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Безопасно, если вынести config.php в отдельную папку закрытую от доступа с браузера, скажем которая выше папки c доступными для браузеров фалами, либо закрыта в htaccess. Но вообще если не произойдет сбой сервера при котором он будет отдавать файлы php как текстовые скорее всего config.php никому не удастся прочитать.

Comment: Эх, долго я сочинял свой ответ. Поэтому только намекну на директиву [``open_basedir``](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Answer (score 2):

А как Вы собираетесь по другому хранить данные для подключения к бд? Далеко не все данные хранимые в php файлах могут быть выведены на экран. Что бы их "прочитать" надо либо получить доступ к серверу (ftp/ssh/sftp) и открыть файл со стороны сервера, либо надо знать как вывести любую переменную php скрипта будучи при этом подключенным как клиент по http. Не давайте переменным очевидных названий, фильтруйте все данные получаемые от пользователей (вообще все, даже куки, и файлы). юзайте htaccess.
Можете сделать не congig.php а /d/e/sa/cs/lal/co/n/f/ig.php :D

Comment: > Не давайте переменным очевидных названий,

какой-то вредный совет.